# How React useState Hook Actually Works?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to use React for my new project but I need to understand the basics, for example how the useState actually works? I did some research about it but still I have one question that didn't answered yet. So this line below increments my "count" variable by 1

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

<button onClick={ () => setCount(count + 1)} />
```

I understand that because I'm setting a new value for count variable, but I did declare count and setCount on same line, so why this doesn't work as expected

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

<button onClick={ () => setCount(+1)} />
```

Isn't setCount is only for "count" variable? Why I should specifically say the variables name?
If I must write variables name in setCount why I cant use it for any other variable? 
Like this

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
const myVar = 0;

<button onClick={ () => setCount(myVar + 1)} />
```

I did research on google, chatGPT and came here for any clerification.

Comment: As far as I know this is completely valid. setCount is the setter function and receives a value of the same type as count (int in your case) but that doesn't mean you can't use other variables, as longe they are all of that type

<button onClick={ () => setCount(myVar + 1)} />

Comment: I am confused about what it is that you are confused about.

Comment: @EdwynZN i did thought that too but it seems it doesnt work properly, see link below
https://codepen.io/somedoga/pen/XWorZQd?editors=1010

Comment: This is logically too easy, I'm not sure why it confuses you? It happens when we tire up ourselves so simple things confuses us, perhaps take a brake and look at it later. If not, why would setting the `count` to `1` (*`setCount(+1)`*) keep magically incrementing the `count` by +1? What if `count` state was an Array and you wanted to push a new item? What do you do then?

Comment: And your `myVar` is set to `0`, so `setCount(0 + 1)` sets `count` to `1`.

Comment: I see your example and it works as intended, decrement has myVar -1 and myVar is always 0, so setCount(-1). Also ocnsider myVar is not a in a hook so that value will always reset to 0 the next frame

Comment: You're not actually asking *"How does it work?"*. You already know how it works. You're asking *"Why does it work this way?"*. And the answer is: ***because other people thought it would be better like this when they developed React***. One thing is for sure: React's `useState` will ***not*** be changed to work the way you're suggesting, because the number of people who think that doesn't make sense is significantly larger than the ones who think it makes sense. Even if the odds were inverted, this would be a breaking change for no gain, therefore it would never get implemented.

Comment: The question could be more elegantly and eloquently be rephrased as *"Why doesn't `count =+ 1` work the same way as `count += 1`?"*. And the answer is: because [expressions and operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_operators). They're one of the most important parts of JavaScript, IMHO. Learn them well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> isn't setCount is only for "count" variable?

Yes

> Why I should specifically say the variables name?

The `setCount` function expects you to pass in a value telling it what the new value of `count` should be. How you calculate the value before you pass it in is up to you. If you can calculate the value without referencing the variable's name, then feel free to do so.

But if you want to do a calculation that uses the old value, you will need to reference that old value in some way. React is not going to do a calculation for you. Thus is you want to take the current value, add 1 to it, and set state to that new value, you will do so via:

```
setCount(count + 1)
```

Or:

```
setCount(prev => prev + 1)
```

Looking at `setCount(+1)` in more detail: javascript will start by evaluating `+1`. That results in just the number `1` (the `+` is redundant). So `1` is passed into setCount, and that sets the state to 1. React has no idea what code you did to produce the `1`. Maybe you did `+1`, maybe you did `6 - 5`, maybe you did `myVar + 1`, where `myVar` is 0.

> why I cant use it for any other variable?
> Like this
>
> ```
> setCount(myVar + 1)
> ```

While it's most common to do a calculation using the previous state, there's nothing stopping you from doing calculations with other variables, if the need arises. The only reason your `myVar` example isn't useful is that `myVar` never changes. It's always `0`, so `myVar + 1` is the same as `0 + 1`, which results in `1`. Thus you end up passing `1` into setCount, and the `count` state changes to `1`.